# Unable to run linphone on android(Ubuntu)

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk, linphone

I downloaded the code from (git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git --recursive) git responsitory and followed the readme.txt file in the dowloaded source code. I installed the autotools as instructed in readme and run make command on my project but missed a point becuase my pc is not 64 bit pc. The point is :

```
    On 64 bits linux systems you'll need the ia32-libs package
    With the latest Debian (multiarch), you need this:
    dpkg --add-architecture i386
    aptitude update
    aptitude install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386
```

So after following all the instructions i successfully builed the project and clean it successfully and got message on console :

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project linphone-android ****

bash /home/redhat/chang_data/chandan/chandan/frommhs/ways/waysAndroid/ways/linphone-android/build_native.sh NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1 all 
bash: /home/redhat/chang_data/chandan/chandan/frommhs/ways/waysAndroid/ways/linphone-android/build_native.sh: No such file or directory

**** Build Finished ****
```

but after that when i run my project it is running on device but got crashed on one point and exception is :

```
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.linphone/org.linphone.LinphoneActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at org.linphone.LinphonePreferences.getConfig(LinphonePreferences.java:74)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at org.linphone.LinphonePreferences.isProvisioningLoginViewEnabled(LinphonePreferences.java:963)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at org.linphone.LinphoneActivity.onCreate(LinphoneActivity.java:145)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
06-19 21:01:41.563: E/AndroidRuntime(9550):     ... 11 more
```

i got exception in this method of class org.linphone.LinphonePreferences

```
public LpConfig getConfig() {
        LinphoneCore lc = getLc();
        if (lc != null)
            return lc.getConfig();

        return LinphoneCoreFactory.instance().createLpConfig(LinphoneManager.getInstance().mLinphoneConfigFile);
    }
```

It is because linphonecorefactory instance is not there because instance method can not found class "org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl".

Please tell me how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Problem is not related to git, i think i missed some library in it.

Comment: How did you solve this? Just ran into the same exact problem..